# Assertion of Type Inference Rules/Type Checking

Tags: compilers, type-theory, type-checking, type-inference

I have a problem in a book I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

I understand the overall type of the expression is boolean and how it derives. (y * x) will be rule 4 (counting from top right). (y * x) + x when evaluated will be rule 3 and the overall expression when evaluated will be rule 5.

What I want to figure out is what is the correct way to illustrate the my working? Can someone give or link an example of the correct way to answer a question like this?

---

**Question 2**
[image]

Proposed solution:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you need to construct a typing derivation which has what you want to prove as a conclusion, and no open premise (i.e., leaves must be axioms, or rules with no premises). In the case of your example, the conclusion will be

$$ int\;x,\,int\;y\;\vdash\;(x < (x \times y) + x) : bool $$

so the proof will start by

$$ {int\;x,\,int\;y\;\vdash\;x : int \quad\quad\quad
  int\;x,\,int\;y\;\vdash\;((x \times y) + x) : int}
  \over {int\;x,\,int\;y\;\vdash\;(x < ((x \times y) + x)) : bool} $$

and then you continue building up the tree until you reach leaves (i.e., rules with no premises). This will immediately be the case in the left branch since you only have a variable.

---

Here is the full proof (as an image):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please illustrate a more advanced example with multiple branches/more entries in a tree?

Comment: I wanted to give you the full typing derivation (the full tree), but there does not seem to be any easy way of writing it here... Anyway, it is really easy because you only need to look at the term you want to type. Only one rule apply for every term shape, for instance in the right branch you will want to apply the rule for the $+$ symbol.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help. I think I roughly understand how to do it but still not 100% sure. Do you have any recommendations for external sources/YouTube videos that will give a full example?

Comment: There are loads of ressources and textbooks, for example http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/index.html. Note that I uploaded an image of the complete proof.

Comment: Thank you! I will message if I need further help.

Comment: Hello, I have attempted another question. Can you please check that I understand the concept correctly please. I have added this under the section 'Question 2'

Comment: There is only one problem: you do not have to carry the constant $10$ around in the context. In fact, $10$ has type $int$ in any context $\Gamma$ (first typing rule).

Comment: Ahh okay thanks. Just one more query, under Question 2, are rules 2 and 3 essentially the opposite of it each other? I perceive rule 2 to say - "if v is int then v can be proved to be varint' and rule 3 to say - "if v is varint then v can be proved to be int'. If this is the case, why are written in different ways? (Rule 2 with no hypotheses on top and Rule 3 with hypotheses on top). Couldn't rule 2 be simplified to 'Γ ⊢ v  varint Γ ⊢ v : int'?

Comment: Yes, they could probably be simplified. There is no real point in going through this $varint$ type.

Comment: Are you familiar with Compilers? Specifically intermediate language translation? If so, can you please look at this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92308/translation-from-intermediate-language-into-three-address-machine-instructions

Comment: A note for future answers: you can draw derivations in LaTeX using `\dfrac{premise1 ... premiseN}{conclusion}`, suitably nested. (The result is not that good when some premise is a nested `dfrac` and some other one is not, but one can simply use `dfrac` on all premises to avoid that case)