# Translation from Intermediate Language into 'three-address' machine instructions

Tags: compilers, language-design

[image]

I am unsure where to start with this. From what I understand so far, 'VAR(x)' corresponds to Rule 2, ':= VAR(x) ' refers to Rule 5 and '+ NUM (1) refers to link 3.

```
a := (b+c)*(-e); becomes
t1 = b + c
t2 = – e
a = t1 * t2
```

I understand the translation above, What I am not that clear about are the recursive rules. How do they influence translations?

Can someone point me towards the right direction?

EDIT: With further research I think I understand the concept of the recursive rules. For rule 1, it seems that the value of 'n' will be stored in R' register.

I think the problem i'm facing is how to formulate an answer with my working.